# Call masterpage function from contentpage in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have a function on masterpage and i want to call it from content page from codebehind.

this is my trying :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert__", string.Format("setStatusBarMessage('{0}',{1});", barMessage, type, ""), true);
```

"setStatusBarMessage" function is declare in masterpage , so this code doesnt working.

setStatusBarMessage is a client side function.

MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Content.master.cs" 

Inherits="F8.CRM.Pages.Content" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function hello() {
        alert('hi mennan');
    }

</script>
```

ContentPage :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Content.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Departman.aspx.cs" Inherits="F8.CRM.Departman" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Objects/StudioSideBox/StudioSideBox.ascx" TagName="StudioSideBox"
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Objects/Baslik/Baslik.ascx" TagName="Baslik" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

     my html...

    <script type="text/javascript">

       my script codes...


    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

This masterpage and content page is under a iframe object.

Comment: is it client side function or ?

Comment: i think there is no need to include the functions explicitly if they are on client side, They should already be on Content page.

Comment: edited , its a client function

Comment: I think you need to call RegisterStartupScript instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock. See raman's answer.

Comment: @Mennan if our answers solved your problem then please accept it.........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok try the following code

I have a function in Master Page that is

```
<script>
    function hello() {
        alert('hi');
    }

</script>
```

Now on content page' page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch", "hello();", true);
}
```

It working. i haven't added any thing to content page.

**Update**

Master page's Code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script>
    function hello() {
        alert('hi');
    }

</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

First Content Page's code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<iframe src="Default2.aspx"></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind Of first Content Page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch", "hello();", true);
}
```

Comment: i create a new solution , masterpage and content page its works.but it didnt work in my working project.I use iframe in content page , is there any problem about this ?

Comment: hmm could you paste your master page's and content page's code so that we can understand the problem is in actual.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for calling master page server side function

```
    MasterPagename ms = Master as MasterPagename ;
    ms.FuctionOnMasterPage();
```

If u r trying to call client side function on master page, the i guess u can call it directly since ur master page and content page function will get rendered on the same html page.

Comment: i try to call by name from content page but i got error didnt found like this function name

Answer (score 0):

**Usually I do it so: In the markup:**

```
<asp:Literal ID="ScriptLit" runat="server" />
```

**In the code behind:**

```
ScriptLit.Text = "<script>functionName();</script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here We can Make a Object of Master Page Class and then we can Call MasterPage Function

```
 MasterPageClassName MyMasterPage = (MasterPageClassName)Page.Master;

 MyMasterPage.Functionname();
```

It will definitely Help you. Try It

Answer (score -2):

Label lbl = (Label)this.Master.FindControl("lblBalance");
            lbl.Text = "Hi";

Comment: Where should this code be placed? What is it doing? What's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Yes, please explain any code you answer with. Code only answers are rarely helpful.