# ASP.Net MasterPage with Bootstrap Popup Modal & Content Pages With Code Behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, bootstrap-modal

I have created an ASP.Net Master page with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Jquery 3.1.0.

***Default.master***

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="Default.master.cs" Inherits="BootStrap_With_ASPDotNet.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>This is My Site Using BootStrap in ASP.Net</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"    integrity="sha384-  BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <!--<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">       </script>-->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>

      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Font Awesome inclusion for the icons on the pages -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text\css" />

     <!-- Adding Google Web Fonts to Bootstrap -->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" />

     <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">  </script>
     <![endif]-->
     <link href="custom/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css" />

     <!-- Adding a web font -->
     <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css />-->

          <script type="text/javascript">
             function openModal() {
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
           }

        </script>  
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
     <!--Bootstrap Modal (Dialog Box / Pop-up Window) Example-->
     <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-dialog" runat="server">
            <div class="modal-content" runat="server">
                <div class="modal-header" runat="server">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-   dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4>This is Modal Header</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body" runat="server">This is Modal Body
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer" runat="server">This is Modal Footer
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">Close</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Bootstrap Model (Dialog Box / Popup Window)-->
  </body>
 </html>
```

As you can see I have placed a Popup Dialog at the bottom of the MasterPage so that every instance of the MasterPage i.e. Content Pages will be use this.

Also I have created a JavaScript Function called 'openModal()' has created at the head of the MasterPage to use across all the content pages.

Now I have created a content page 'WebForm1.aspx' using the previously created MasterPage and added a button. Please refer the code below.

***WebForm1.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master"
        AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
        Inherits="BootStrap_With_ASPDotNet.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnClickMe" runat="server" OnClick="btnClickMe_Click"
     Text="Click Me" CssClass="btn btn-danger"/>
</asp:Content>
```

What I want is when I click the button it should show the popup and I need to do it from code behind. See below what I have tried.

```
protected void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
}
```

However it's not working. I can't figure it out why. So could someone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Check the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782928/call-masterpage-function-from-contentpage-in-asp-net

Comment: Nope it's not what I want.

Comment: Any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by my self. Please refer the below information.

1. First place the below JS code in the .

   ```
        function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
   ```
2. Second In server side on button click add the below function()

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { openModal(); });", true);

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others in search for Bootstrap 4 Modal not showing up.
I use master page and have the modal inside a child page, jquery 3.2.1 and bootstrap 4 beta 2.

If the modal do not show up, check the page source, and see if you can find it there.
When you find the modal, it will most likely have change id.

Use .modal or whatever class name used on the modal to be sure hit the it.

Javascript part also need to be before the the child page loads, as the code behind run when if gets to that content part.

Javascript (masterpage head tag):

function openModal() { $('.modal').modal('show'); }

code behind (child page):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "openModal();", true);

This code behind also works.

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "openModal();", true);