# Calling javascript function from C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using the geodata API that gives me all countries,states,cities in the world in three different select `Lists`.

These `Lists` can not be server side. These `Lists` take some time to load the options.
I wanna set a specific country, state and city from my `C#` code behind as selected in the select `Lists`.
I tried using `clientScript` and `scriptManager` in order to call a `Javascript` function that will set the country, state and city as selected, yet both methods didn't call the function. below is my code:

**The select `Lists` code:**

```
       <tr>              
            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #000080;">
                Country:</td>
            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <select id="countryId" class="countries order-alpha"  name="country">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                </select>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="countryValue" runat="server" />


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #000080;">
                District:</td>
            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <select id="stateId" class="states order-alpha"  name="state">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                </select>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="stateValue" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #000080;">
                City:
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style3" style="border-color: #FFFFFF; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <select id="cityId" class="cities order-alpha"  name="city">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/countrystatecity.js"></script>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="cityValue" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**The Javascript function:**

```
function fillCities(countryName, districtName, cityName)
{
    var country = document.getElementById("countryId")
    country.value = countryName;

    var district = document.getElementById("stateId")
    district.value = districtName;

    var city = document.getElementById("cityId")
    city.value = cityName;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose You're assign the value from code behind to Hidden field

```
countryValue.Value = "India";
stateValue.Value = "Maharashtra";
cityValue.Value = "Mumbai";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "com", "CallJavaScriptFun();", true);
```

> and then calling the javascript method...the above code is set from code behind...

```
 function CallJavaScriptFun() {

            var countryValue = document.getElementById('<% =countryValue.ClientID %>').value;//here you will get the value of hidden field and assign to client side id....in our case it should be "India" as Value
            var country = document.getElementById('countryId');
            country = countryValue;

            var districtName = document.getElementById('<% =stateValue.ClientID %>').value; 
            var district = document.getElementById("stateId")
            district.value = districtName;

            var cityName = document.getElementById('<% =cityValue.ClientID %>').value;
            var city = document.getElementById("cityId")
            city.value = cityName;
        }
```

> All the hidden field countryValue,stateValue,cityValue are stored in
>   respectively variable...
>
> and then assign to client side id....

and Follow this answer also....

[How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

> After Edit-

You have to put this javascript function into head part....check out this image...i have already tested it out...it's working fine...

[image]

Comment: I tried what you had suggested, but the RegisterStartupScript didnt call the javascript function for some reason.

Comment: @@Erel i have edited my answer..check out....open the image in full screen

Comment: im using a masterpage in this page, maybe that is the problem? i placed a breakpoint at the start of the javascript function, and it never activates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782928/call-masterpage-function-from-contentpage-in-asp-net

Comment: thanks! apparently the breakpoint i set at the beginning of the javascript function didn't work, even though the function activated.